# Java: How to call upon a method in a main class where the method is in another class which extends an abstract class

Tags: java, program-entry-point, abstract

I have been asked to create a main method that allows me to create a wolf object, parrot object and rhino object, I have created classes for each of these animals and they extend the abstract class animal which contains an abstract method makeNoise(). I have implemented this abstract method within my rhino, parrot and wolf classes and the method contains a System.out.println function and the noise associated with each of these animals. For example my parrot class(which extends animal) contains a method makeNoise() which prints out "squawk".

I have been asked to demonstrate that I can call upon this makeNoise method for each of my animal objects in the main class, how do I go about doing this?

```
public class Main() {
     Wolf myWolf = new Wolf();
     //I want my wolf to make a noise here

     Parrot myParrot = new Parrot();
     //I want my parrot to make a noise here

     Rhino myRhino = new Rhino();
     //I want my rhino to make a noise here
}
```

Comment: You/they probably meant "main **method**", not "main *class*"? Also, your code is not valid Java, you're mixing class and method semantics.

Comment: Does `myWolf.makenoise()` not work?

Comment: In order to prove they are related to each other, you could do `Animal[] animals = { myWolf, myParrot, myRhino }; for (Animal a : animals) { a.makeNoise(); }`

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not even valid Java, you're mixing class and method semantics (and, most likely, the concepts behind them).

Your class will need a [main method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN) to make your class executable from the outside.

```
public class Main {
     Wolf myWolf = new Wolf();
     Parrot myParrot = new Parrot();
     Rhino myRhino = new Rhino();

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         myWolf.makeNoise();
         myParrot.makeNoise();
         myRhino.makeNoise();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Main
{
    Animal myWolf = new Wolf();
    Animal myParrot = new Parrot();
    Animal myRhino = new Rhino();

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println(myWolf.makeNoise());
        System.out.println(myParrot.makeNoise());
        System.out.println(myRhino.makeNoise());
    }
}
```

Because Animal is an abstract class which has the abstract method `makeNoise()`, it's fine to use the abstract class itself and allocate it any of its child classes which implements the said method. The different allocations demonstrates polymorphism wherein `makeNoise()` can have varying interpretations. Changing `Parrot` to `Rhino` will thus result in a different implementatio of `makeNoise()`.

Comment: I was only following the code extract given by the OP and improving it. Still surprised I'm downvoted.

Comment: You should have corrected the code in OP rather than correcting the logic in the wrong code

Comment: @Adil, regardless I've answered the question, even if the way it has been answered doesn't agree with cynics.

Comment: @Poriferous just correct the code you posted. For the votes, this is how it works, but keep in mind that you could get upvotes for this answer if the code is correct (and other downvotes aswell if you don't correct it), so I would juste correct it

Comment: @RC Of course you can correct it. I don't know what's wrong with the code since it's just using the code provided by the OP as a base.

Comment: the I in "so I would juste correct it" was you in my mind. But there I did fix the code..